# Getting an Invoke error in Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode

Has

```
func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
    var todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:]
    let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)
    *return items.map({TodoItem(deadline: $0["deadline"] as NSDate, title: $0["title"] as String, UUID: $0["UUID"] as String!)}).sorted({
    return ($0.deadline.compare($1.deadline) == .OrderedAscending)
})
}
```

I am getting this error on the line with the asterisk:

```
cannot invoke ‘sorted’ with an argument list of type ‘((_. _)->_)'
```

Has anyone had this issue, or do you know why the error is there?